# What is the procedure for scheduling on the ISS if an astronaut oversleeps?

Tags: astronauts, sleep

From [the accepted answer to this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39827/did-any-astronauts-on-a-mission-complain-about-waking-up) there have been times when astronauts have overslept.

> The morning started disastrously. I slept through two alarms, one set for 0600 and another a half-hour later to remind me to take some COE pictures. My body apparently went on strike for better working conditions.

Given the intense scheduling pressure, what are the procedures for handling a thirty minute or more oversleep?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find a good source for this, so commenting in lieu of answer for now, but I used to be able to view schedules and while "down to five minutes" is kind of accurate, there tended to be some time around the scheduled sleep times for hygiene or exercise that could be used as a buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm probably going to miss actually answering your question about a procedure for handling oversleeps, if one exists.  I think this answer will be worthwhile info on scheduling on the ISS anyway.

First, though, the closest thing I could find to a crewmember answering your actual question.  This is from [NASA/TM-2010-216130](https://lsda.jsc.nasa.gov/lsda_data/dataset_inv_data/ILSRA_2001_104__1740256372_.pdf_Expedition_8_ILSRA-2001-104_2011_31_010100.pdf), the first of the two Stuster papers I linked previously.:

> Skipped breakfast and finally made up the work and time. Otherwise it would have been a fairly nice pace today.

Schedule is a frequent subcategory of journal entries in both Stuster papers.  Both have a portion of "Section 4: Implications" dedicated specifically to "Schedules and Time-Related Stress."  Recurring themes to do with scheduling are that the ground schedulers have difficulties making good estimates as to the length of time any given task will take, and so schedules are often blown even without sleep issues.

- Only  30  minutes  [were  scheduled]  to  execute  a  55-step  procedure  that  required  collecting  21  items. It took 3 or 4 hours.
- Had an uneventful rendezvous and docking, but then had to work quite a few hours that day in order  to  unpack  the  Soyuz  and  ready  it  for  an  emergency  landing  if  necessary.  I  found  myself  getting  pretty  inefficient;  by  the  time  I  go  to  bed  tonight  my  work  day  will  have  been  about  27  hours, and that’s on top of 2 nights with pretty minimal sleep. I don’t know what could be done about it, but I think they should give us time off after docking.
- It  has  been  a  pretty  tedious  week  with  tasks  that  were  clearly  allotted  too  little  time  on  the  schedule. Talking to [the MCC] today, I realized he just doesn’t understand how we work up here.
- Several of the procedures, as usual, just took much longer than timelined. We have some tasks, as  is  too  often  the  case,  that  were  written  without  our  input  and  which  we  never  actually  performed, except on paper.  *[Erin's note - I have bad memories of trying to develop software procedures as the software developer.  Quite the CF.  Sorry astronauts, I tried.]*

There's more in the second paper,  [NASA/TM-2016-218603](https://web.archive.org/web/20190411152743/https://ston.jsc.nasa.gov/collections/TRS/_techrep/TM-2016-218603.pdf):

- I suspect the reality is that  few, if any, have been able to  accomplish the tasks on-time, at least this  early  in  flight  before  we  have  locations  and  common  procedures memorized. Telling  the ground that it took longer to perform a task than scheduled is an admission of lack of ability. And telling the ground a little  more privately, through typing a crew note  in OSTPV, well, takes  even more time.  It’s low on my priority list when I’m pressing on to the next task.
- The  fatigue  from  these  busy  weeks  comes  not  from  physical  labor  but  from  mental  strain.  No matter  what  the  ground  tells  us,  we  still  feel  the  need  to  chase  the  red  line  on  OSTPV.  And  we are constantly aware that the ground is watching and evaluating.

Essentially:  you just do what you can.  There's an ongoing feedback loop between the schedulers and the astronauts.  A lot does have to get done, but ultimately the crew and the schedulers are both human and the schedule will inevitably take hits from that.